# How to add jar file in VS Code in my project?

Tags: java, javafx, visual-studio-code

I am trying to use VS Code to do a javafx project. I just figured out that javafx isn't built in in Java 13.(However, I remember that it is included before?)

So I download the javafx sdk and try to add the jar files into my project. I have added codes like`<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib\javafx-swt.jar"/>` into the .classpath file. And the Java Dependencies also shows the included jar files. However, when I compiled the program it will show package does not exist. I'm wondering if I took any wrong step adding these jar files?

[This is what my javafx code look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IYal5.png)

[The .classpath file and error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ais4L.png)

Comment: You might do yourself a huge favor, using a **maven** build infrastructure, that takes care of library dependencies. And though I very much like VS, using say IntelliJ Community Edition would give a better language support.

Comment: Thanks a lot for leaving the comment. I'll give it a try.

Comment: try to change to `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="lib/javafx-swt.jar"/>` ,use  `/` and move it above `<classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/> `

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have tried your way but it seems still not working. Is there anything else to do beside changing `/` and move them above?

Comment: I've solve the problem with **maven** to build the project. Thank you all for the help.